# SerialPort.getCommPorts() does not return list of ttyS*

Tags: java, serial-port

I used Fazecast/jSerialComm to develop a simple serial communication Java project. However, `SerialPort.getCommPorts()`  did not return an array of `ttyS*` on my Dell R710 server, which should list `ttyS[0123]` (4 ports) on my RHEL 6 OS.

I plugged one USB serial cable into the same machine, and it returned the USB serial device (`ttyUSB0`). I had tried the COM board on the server to send a file to another server with Minicom and it worked, so I knew the port functioned OK.

Does my project need to do something else before I can inquire about the port list on server? Or did I miss some setting on my RHEL 6 OS on this server for the ports?

Comment: I used usermod to add  (-a) to dialog and tty and lock to session user  (sudo usermod -a -G dialog currentuser ) and reboot the machine now it is ok. Thanks.

Comment: Turn this into an answer and format your question, this might yield the first 10 reputation for you

Comment: I was going to suggest a permissions issue. Since that sounds like what the problem was, it would be helpful for other people for you to post that as an answer to your own question.